# How to return true if all values in column are true, and false otherwise?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with boolean values and want to return only one boolean value based on the truth value of the whole column e.g. if every entry in the column is true then return true, otherwise, return false.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres supports [`bool_and()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) or the equivalent:

```
select bool_and(col)
from t;
```

There are other methods.  For instance:

```
select count(*) filter (where col) = count(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask PG if there does not exist any false value

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT null FROM t WHERE NOT boolcolumn);
```

If any value is false, the subquery will return at least one row. EXISTS will report true, which is flipped to false. The only way to get true out of it is for the subquery to return no rows, which only happens when all are true

You might find it more logical as

```
SELECT TRUE = ALL (SELECT boolcol FROM t)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Select case when Count(BooleanField)=Sum(BooleanField) then 1 Else 0 End  as Result 
From MyTable
```